# Scroll issue when placing an webview within a scrollview

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I am having an issue with the scrooling of webview when i have placed the webview within a scroll view whch inturn is under a frame layout

Below is the mentioned layout for my requirement

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".WebSampleActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                  <Button
                      android:id="@+id/button_view"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="button" />
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:onClick="true" 
                    />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above example when i touch the webview area my conent gets scrolled bellow the button which is placed in the layout

Could anyone please tell me how to handle this isuue. 
I need the conent in the webview only to move till the button area

Comment: can you be bit more clear please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your issue, but, try to change the LinearLayout param to:

```
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/button_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button" />
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:onClick="true" 
                />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I think that it can work.

If you want to don't loss the button, you must change the LinearLayout and ScrollView.